# FTP on Mac M2 failing -- Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, ftp

I am trying to connect to FTP from a M2 Mac

```
brew install tnftp
ftp -nv $ADDRESS
```

Gives an error

```
Connected to $ADDRESS
220-
 <Banner ...>
220 FTP Server ready.
331 Anonymous login ok, send your complete email address as your password
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Further info:

```
otool -L `which ftp`
~/.homebrew/bin/ftp:
    /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
```

I am seeing that this may somehow be related to libraries but not sure what steps I can take to figure the exact cause

Comment: How have you installed homebrew `~/.homebrew/bin/ftp` is an odd path I think

Comment: this path is irrelevant unless you have suggestion. This is the location I point my brew to

Comment: How did the code get there - brews path is by default /usr/lib/bin or /opt/homebrew/bin I am not certain it is tested anywhere else

Comment: as said, it is the default path that I've set when installing brew to avoid having to sudo every time

Comment: Umm, the whole point of using brew is to avoid using `sudo` in general use. If you think you have to use `sudo` to use brew you are grossly misinformed. I'd suggest you delete all of your current brew installation and reinstall it in the proper location. Then you are likely to get either a working system, or some help if you can show it still doesn't work.